# Cocos2D HD spriteWithFile displays in SD

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, retina

I'm using Cocos2D 2.1 and this app is planned to be iPad only retina and non-retina. When I use spriteWithFile, and specify the filename without the -hd suffix, Cocos2D finds the image with the -hd suffix and uses it, but it displays in standard definition, meaning it doesn't scale down so it's displaying as a retina image.

In my delegate's - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions method, I have the following:

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

[glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];

[director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

[director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];


// attach the openglView to the director
[director_ setView:glView];

// 2D projection
[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];

[director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES];

//  // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:NO] )
    CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

// If the 1st suffix is not found and if fallback is enabled then fallback suffixes are going to searched. If none is found, it will try with the name without suffix.
CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO]; // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used

[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];

glView.opaque = NO;
glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
//glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Assume that PVR images have premultiplied alpha
[CCTexture2D PVRImagesHavePremultipliedAlpha:YES];
```

When I add the sprite using spriteWithFile (instead of using a sprite sheet because it's only one image) I have the following code:

```
movingTileGroup.handleSprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"draggableTileGroupHandle.png"];

movingTileGroup.handleSprite1.position = ccp(x,y);

[self.theMap addChild:movingTileGroup.handleSprite1 z:13];
```

**Update**: I see when -(BOOL) enableRetinaDisplay:(BOOL)enabled is called, none of the if statements return true. Could it have to do with a scale factor setting?

```
-(BOOL) enableRetinaDisplay:(BOOL)enabled
{
    NSLog(@"enableRetinaDisplay called");
    // Already enabled ?
    if( enabled && __ccContentScaleFactor == 2 ){
        NSLog(@"enabled && __ccContentScaleFactor == 2 ");
        return YES;
    }

    // Already disabled
    if( ! enabled && __ccContentScaleFactor == 1 ){
        NSLog(@"! enabled && __ccContentScaleFactor == 1 ");
        return YES;
    }

    // setContentScaleFactor is not supported
    if (! [__view respondsToSelector:@selector(setContentScaleFactor:)]){
        NSLog(@"setContentScaleFactor is not supported");
        return NO;
    }
    // SD device
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 1.0){
        NSLog(@"SD device");
        return NO;
    }

    float newScale = enabled ? 2 : 1;
    [self setContentScaleFactor:newScale];

    // Load Hi-Res FPS label
    [[CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils] buildSearchResolutionsOrder];
    [self createStatsLabel];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Spritebuilder to generate sprites , if that is so you need to specify the default size of the image in the spritebuilder software, this can be done by clicking on the image which is showing the problem and then on the left sidebar or panel select the image size as "default" and it will automatically scale to the required size...

If this doesn't solves your problem, Do let me know... regards...

Comment: I'm using Zwoptex for making spritesheets, but in this case I'm only using a single png image, so there's no need for spritesheets. (This is why I'm using spriteWithFile)
It may just be that it's required that I use a spritesheet that specifies the width and height so it knows to display properly in retina.

Comment: Another thing I found out is that I can't get retina graphics to work with a spritesheet on my main game layer, but they do on my custom parallax layer.  Thanks for putting some thoughts into this, but I think I will make a new thread based on these findings and close this one.